# condition variable timeout not understood

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I am playing to try to give a timeout to a thread.
I try to use [std::condition_variable::wait_for](http://it.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) but this behaves differently than I would expect.

Here my simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex myMutex;

void waitSec(int seconds)
{
    std::cout <<"t1 start" <<std::endl;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(seconds));
    std::cout <<"t1 end" <<std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    // launch thread that sleeps 10s
    std::thread t1(waitSec,10);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    // wait for lock during max 1 second
    std::condition_variable* conditionVariable = new std::condition_variable();
    std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
    conditionVariable->wait_for(lock,std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "after" << std::endl;

    t1.join();
}
```

I expect Thread T1 to sleeps for 10 seconds. Since I give 1s timeout to the `wait_for` in the main thread I would expect that `after` is printed before `t1 end`.

What happens instead is that t1 runs for 10 seconds, (printing `t1 end`) and just 1s after `after` is printed.

Can you explain me why it behaves like this and what should I do to get my timeout performing as a timeout?

Comment: it looks like t1 locked myMutex and main thread should wait until it releases it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `condition_variable`. You have a `unique_lock` in `waitSec` before your 10 seconds sleep so no one will be able to acquire the mutex for 10 seconds so this line:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
```

Will wait until the end of `waitSec` and the release of `mutex` by the `unique_lock` destructor.

You need to create your `condition_variable` before any other thread locked your mutex.

Comment: thanks... this helped... so i created the lock at the beginning of the main. Then since this automatically lock the mutex i called the unlock. Thanks!

Comment: @Stefano You should not unlock the mutex manually, the `wait_for` (and other `wait`s method) of `condition_variable` do that for you (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait).

Comment: nono... it was because i wanted to create the lock in the main without locking it... i just discovered that i can create this using as second param std::defer_lock

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use conditional variables in this case, as you just sleep 1 second in the main thread after t1 start.

What is actually happened that you have locked the mutex in the thread 1:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
```

then in the main thread you are trying to lock this mutex again (after the return from 1 second sleep):

```
std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
```

The main thread will able to obtain this lock only after t1 will be finished (~9 seconds, total 10 sesconds). Then the program will print "before" and successfully obtain lock and will wait for any event for 1 second, because:

```
conditionVariable->wait_for(lock,std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

And there is nobody can wake (notify) the main thread from the waiting, so it will just calmly sleep for 1 second and then prints "after"

So effectively you can get what do you want just removing mutex locking from the thread function. As your threads not interacting/share resourses with each-other

If you need to wait was one second or until thread is finished you can do something like this (please note that this code not ideal, just to show the basic idea):

```
std::condition_variable cv;

void worker_thread()
{
    // do something
    // ...
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main() {
   std::thread t1(worker_thread);

   std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
   cv.wait_for(lock,std::chrono::seconds(1));
   std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: right... What i want to achieve is just giving a timeout to the t1 procedure... if after 1s has not finished main thread should just carry on. Do you know how could i do this?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your mutex is locked, not because of the condition variable.

in main() you try to acquire the mutex in the 1 line here:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
conditionVariable->wait_for(lock,std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

However your thread t1 holds the mutex here:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(seconds));
```

Thus the code in main() cannot proceed until the mutex in the `waitSec` function run by the t1 thread is released, which happens when the function ends.

Don't hold mutexes while sleeping.